# How can I cancel audio feedback from mic while playing an audio track in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-audio, web-audio-api

Given my current situation:

- an input track (microphone; it is not output)
- an output track (an audio file)

I can hear the output track on the input track. Is there a way to implement some kind of phase cancellation on the input track, so as to avoid hearing the played audio file in a feedback/echo loop?

I have tried using `noiseSuppression: true` and `echoCancellation: true` constraints, to no effect. Thanks everyone